# Using a compiled Python shell in Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to use a "more complex" shell than just a single command shell?  We have written a python shell that is a command loop, and it works fine in `/etc/passwd` like this:

```
user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/usr/bin/ourshell.py
```

Of course the Python file has the shebang line for `/usr/bin/python` in it.  However, we'd like to compile the Python shell into a `.pyc` file to save a bit of time on execution in login.  So, after compiling, I've been trying to "quote" the shell line in `/etc/passwd` as "python ourshell.pyc", and I even tried making the shell a bash script which simply executes that same command (with the initial arguments).

Of course none of this has worked.  When we SSH in, there is always some kind of error. Is there any special trick to what I am trying to do?

Comment: "there is always some kind of error".  How about show the errors you have.

Comment: Whatever delay you may be experiencing with `ourshell.py` starting probably as far more to do with the Python interpreter itself than the time it takes to compile `ourshell.py`.

Comment: I highly recommend against [using `/usr/bin/python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

Comment: @NathanSmith The correct thing to do is let whoever is *installing* the script choose the shebang, not the person writing the script. The installer knows where the correct version of Python is. `distutils` manages this by replacing `#!python` with the correct path at install time.

Comment: It's **extremely** unlikely that loading this module as a .pyc file will save any appreciable amount of time unless it's incredibly complex to parse (in which case you should refactor it for unrelated reasons). Usually Python-interpreter startup time is driven by the time to load library modules.

Comment: The strict reasoning here is that we are using the SSH "exec" protocol, which executes the shell with a single command argument -c.  I did a sample test run of 2000 commands using both "ourshell.py -c ..". and "python ourshell.pyc -c ..." and the average time went from 6.5 seconds to 5.5 seconds.  And this means a lot since we're scripting a lot of devices and need the time savings.

Comment: That falls into the "ought to be refactored" category, then. If you were using setuptools to build the executable wrapper for your script, for instance (see the `console_scripts` entry in `setup.py`), then the generated wrapper would be extremely short and simple to parse, and would just be loading a (pre-parsed to .pyc, if you installed it correctly) library and executing same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPython's `.pyc` files are not text, and do not allow use of a shebang line. The traditional method is to have your called script be tiny; it would simply import a module with the rest of the program, which can then be precompiled. For instance, here is the main script of [xonsh](http://xon.sh/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 -u
from xonsh.main import main
main()
```

This script takes negligible time to compile. It is also possible to run installed modules using `-m`, but that takes module names, not filenames, so is not suitable for a shebang script.

Comment: CPython can run bytecode just as it runs source code, no command line option is needed

Comment: I was mistaken. It does carry a potential downside in that the precompiled format is version specific, though, and isn't shebang compatible... one could use binfmt_misc on Linux to make these executable then. I suspect users wouldn't appreciate being suddenly unable to login when Python is upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to code a small C wrapper program running your python shell.

(notice that [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) forbids nested [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) interpreters; I don't know if that applies for your case)

Look into your log files, probably `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/auth.log`

You may also need to explicitly add (the compiled C executable for the wrapper) to `/etc/shells`; see [shells(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html)

Look also into [scsh](https://scsh.net/).

Your `sshd` daemon is probably using Linux Plugin Authentification Modules. So read more about [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/).

Comment: It's Dropbear for ARM

From the log:

Sep  1 19:41:48 InovaOnAlert-d28 authpriv.info dropbear[24120]: Exit (user): Child failed
Sep  1 19:41:48 InovaOnAlert-d28 authpriv.err dropbear[24120]: chown /dev/pts/0 0 0 failed: Operation not permitted
Sep  1 19:41:48 InovaOnAlert-d28 authpriv.info dropbear[24119]: Exit (user): Disconnect received

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `/usr/bin/shell_wrapper` that contains this one line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ourshell.pyc
```

The compiled bytecode `ourshell.pyc` has to live in `/usr/bin`, or else change the path accordingly. The `python` path should go to the same version that compiled the bytecode.

Then make sure to have your `/etc/passwd` use `/usr/bin/shell_wrapper` for the shell executable:

```
user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/usr/bin/shell_wrapper
```